# c# / XAML - ListView grouping: Changing the (background) color of the first header only

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, grouping

In my WPF Application, I have this ListView:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                <Expander.Header>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22"
                               Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold"
                               FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" Ergebnis(se)" FontSize="22"
                               Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
              </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
  </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Now I want the first - and only the first - Header to appear in a different color (than the rest of the Headers - Font Color or Background Color, I don't care) for it to be marked.
I can't for the hell of it come up with an idea on how to do it.

Comment: you already showing text inside header in different color, what you wanna achieve here? you want background of header in color?

Comment: No I want the FIRST - and only the first - header to appear in a different color than the other headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "header"? Do you want to change background of the first Expander?

Comment: @mm8 yes sir! That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a converter class that returns a specific `Brush` for the first group only:

```
public class GroupConverter : IValueConverter
{
    int n;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return n++ == 0 ? Brushes.Yellow  : Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:GroupConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=" Ergebnis(se)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Grid Background="White">
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as converter will execute for all the items in the list

Comment: Of course it will. So will a data trigger and anything else. This is how ItemsControl and loops work...The template and GroupStyle is applied to all items - always.

Comment: Since he need always the first item, directly achieve through ItemContainerGenerator

Comment: This won't work since the he wants to change the colour of the Expander in the *GroupStyle*. He doesn't want to modify the ListViewItekm container.

Comment: @mm8 Where does the c# class go? Does it need to be code-behind (I use mvvm).

Comment: @mm8 and how does it work? How does XAML know the converter to be used is an instance of GroupConverter?

Comment: It's a simple stand-alone class. Just create a new one under Project->Add Class in Visual Studio.

Comment: Converters are pretty basic in WPF. You can read more about how they work here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/.

Answer (score 0):

`Converter` in WPF is very costly as it will execute for each `ListViewItem`. Since the requirement is to apply style always for the first item, `VisualTreeHelper` will be best fit for the solution.

```
var expander = GetElement<Expander>(myListView);
// Do expander style changes
```

Below is a generic method to get the element from the Visual Tree.

```
public T GetElement<T>(Visual element)
{
        T foundElement = default(T);
        if (element == null) return foundElement;
        if (element.GetType() == typeof(T)) return (T)Convert.ChangeType(element, typeof(T));

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = GetElement<T>(visual);
            if (foundElement != null) break;
        }
        return foundElement;
    }
```